# Changing my visa (student to work permit) - Germany

Tags: visa, germany, working-visas, student-visa, students

I`ve finished a master degree here in Germany. I concluded my degree on october/20 but because the corona situation I received a certificate just on the the middle of January. Then, the company I wrote my master thesis offered me a job which I've already started on 01.03.2021.

I know I need to change my visa, but for the work permit visa I need my contract, a stellenbeschreibung and my certificate from the university (as informed by auslanderbehorde). I received the contract documents 2 days before start to work. Moreover, the structure of my salary (Tarifwerk) was not described and I needed it to proof I have the minimum as required for the bluecard . I've explained the company and they will provide that for me.

The main question is that I've already started to work with a student visa and I am planning to apply for a work permit as soon as I receive the document from the company. Is it legal to start working a fulltime job without a work visa, just with a student visa ? Which consequences could I face?

Answer (score 1):

In general case, there should be no problem. Normally, student residence permits also include the permission to work 120 full days per year or 240 half days per year. I would assume, in general case, a student can start working with that permission and get new residence permit later.

However, if one does not have a work permit at all, he/she should not start working on the first working day.

It is also unclear, if Blue Card is the best option. At least it is not the only option, cause in Germany there are multiple types of residence permits for the purpose of work. If a student has finished education in Germany, [he can get the permanent residence permit after 2 years of having a regular residence permit for the purpose of work](https://www.berlin.de/labo/willkommen-in-berlin/dienstleistungen/service.245678.php/dienstleistung/326558/standort/327805/), which is similar to Blue Card.